# Name for the set {Mv : |v| = 1}

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Let $M$ be a matrix on a normed vector space.
Is there a name for the set $\{Mv : |v| = 1\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image of the unit sphere under $M$.